# ActivityIndicator won't turn off after control property is set to false

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Im using Anuglar6 and Nativescript trying to make the ActivityIndicator show when i do api work (login). That works fine but but after i set the Boolean processing to false it stills shows the spinning animation.

```html
<StackLayout class="container">
  <StackLayout class="form">
    <Label class="h3 lbl" text="Användarnamn:" textWrap="true"></Label>
    <TextField class="field input input-border" [isEnabled]="!processing" keyboardType="email" autocapitalizationType="none" (textChange)="setUsername($event)" (returnPress)="focusPassword()"></TextField>
    <Label class="h3 lbl" text="Lösenord:" textWrap="true"></Label>
    <TextField #password class="field input input-border" [isEnabled]="!processing" secure="true" autocapitalizationType="none" (textChange)="setPassword($event)"></TextField>
    <Button class="loginBtn" text="LOGGA IN" [isEnabled]="!processing" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
    <ActivityIndicator row="1" [busy]="processing" width="100" height="100" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

```
    private processing = false;

    public login(): void {
    this.processing = true;
    this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
        .subscribe(
            () => {
                console.log(this.processing);
                this.processing = false;
                console.log(this.processing);
                // this.router.navigate(['home']);
            });
}
```

The console.log printout

```
JS: true
JS: false
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: what property on the indicator do you bind the `processing` variable to?

Comment: Can you share the complete code with HTML?

Comment: `[busy]="processing"`

Comment: Try removing width and height attributes from ActivityIndicator.

Comment: Removed them but still nothing. This is so strange :D

Comment: you should also use the `visible` property, and if youre using angular, remove the `<Page>` tags

Comment: Okey, thanks. Can u tell me how to use the visible property? Cant find it in the docs?

Comment: I guess you are talking about this: `[visibility]="processing ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"`? But the ActivityIndicator don't seem to show with just this? It seems to need the `[busy]` property to show?

Comment: you need both, or you did in v2 and to my knowledge, it hasnt changed

Comment: They dont use it in the examples in the docs: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ng-ui-widgets-category/activity-indicator/setting-busy-http-request

Comment: The code should work as expected - here is a simplified Playground demo of the exact same scenario https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=uKdrbq

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for all your help in the matter. I did not want to have to click the button one more time to close the ActivityIndicator. I wanted it to turn off after login task was finished. The data was updated but the ui was not. I solved it with a BehaviorSubject.

```
public processing$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

public login(): void {
    this.processing$.next(true);
    this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
        .subscribe(
            () => {
                console.log(this.processing$);
                this.processing$.next(false);
                console.log(this.processing$);
                this.router.navigate(['home']);
            });
}
```

Now it updates the ui accordingly.